# Trimble RTX GPS NTRIP, DNS failed to resolve IP address

Tags: gps, trimble

I'm trying to get the RTX correction service going with my Trimble BX992. It is a CenterPoint RTX correction, for which I can see that I am correctly subscribed. I'm getting down to ~0.2m 1-sigma errors, which is pretty nice, but in the `I/O Configuration->Port Configuration` page I can see that the NTRIP client's status is: *DNS failed to resolve IP address* (including a screenshot). I was told that in the `I/O Configuration->Port Summary` page I should see a green row for the NTRIP Client, with "CMRxe" in the input column; however, I get a yellow row, with nothing in the input column (attached a screenshot).

My device is not connected to the internet at all times, and has a fixed IP address for a local network, which I don't know if it is part of the problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue on another RTX device, and I think there are a couple of important issues to comment on.

First of all, you did not mention it, but you NEED to have internet on the receiver. RTX works both with satellite connection and internet to get the measurements. If you don't have internet on the GPS antenna, it may say RTX is activated, but you will not be receiving any corrections.

Once you get that working, you must make sure the IP Setup under Network Configuration->Ethernet is on DHCP, and not Static IP. That should solve the issue.

Comment: How Does Trimble RTX Technology work? Frequently_Asked_Questions https://positioningservices.trimble.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Trimble_RTX_Frequently_Asked_Questions.pdf confirms this requirement when collecting GPS data. IP/Cellular required on the Trimble GPS for RTX

Comment: Changing the settings to DHCP and allowing it to be connected to the internet solved the problem. Thank you both!